# Unit tests for Rest API

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have to write unit tests for Rest API in my web application.

The front-end of the web application is written in Reactjs
The back-end of it is written in python Flask.

I have to write unit tests for the Rest API calls for this application to test the response of the API calls.

Can anyone please suggest me a better framework for writing REST API unit tests for my web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There is no problem with it, the application has already been developed and I am asked to write unit tests for Rest API calls made by the application. I have been asked to write test cases to check if the response I get from the API call is as expected. Can you suggest me any unit test frameworks for carrying out such kind of tests.

Comment: If you are using google chrome browser than go for `postman` or if you are using mozila firefox browser than go for `RESTClient`. Both are add-ons and are used for rest api testing. Google about it and you will come to know how easy it is to use them. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try using them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your API is written in Flask because of your tag. So in that case Flask has some built in tools for unit testing that you can use - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/

Here is an example of a simple REST API that I created and wrote tests for - https://github.com/tim-thompson/bonsai-trees/blob/master/tests.py

This way you can automate the tests as part of a build process without having to use an external tool such as Postman.